# CSS background-image issue for <select> & <option>

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, html-select

**HTML**

```
<select data-val="true"  id="GameID" >
   <option value="">Select Game...</option>
   <option value="4">Counter Strike Source</option>
   <option value="5">Medal Of Honor</option>
   <option value="6">NFS Shift</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
select
{
    color: #fff;
    background: url(/img/backgrounds/tab-hover-background.png) rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    border: 1px solid #8093BE;
    width: 242px;
    height: 20px;   
}

option
{
    background: url(/img/backgrounds/tab-hover-background.png) rgba(0,0,0,0); 
}
```

- In Firefox it works fine,
- In Opera it works only for select,but not for option
- In IE 9.0 & Chrome it has a strange behavior
  **I want all browsers to display like Firefox**

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/kr7R5/) is a source

Comment: **NOTE** as of 2022 and Firefox version 105 this browser now longer shows background images on select options. This previously worked really well but at some point the browser developers decided to change things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not that easy to change form element's style.. each browser has it's [own way to render and create those elements](http://swatelier.info/at/forms/select.htm). Some browsers will accept having a background image inside your select, others won't.

A simple technique is to add a default color, so the browser will render the color if it cant render the image.

```
background: #c3c3c3 url(http://www.3dtuning.ru/img/design/gallery-back.png) repeat-x 0 0;
```

so this way, firefox users will see a background image (something that always looks ugly, in my opinion) and the rest of the browsers will display with a gray background.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Your alpha transparency is set to 0 in the `RGBa` values, this means that it will be completely transparent/not visible, this needs to be set to 1 for it to be visible.

Also, you need to put your `RGBa` value before the `url('image.jpg')`.

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous post: color comes before image url.
in stead of rgba(0,0,0,0) you better use the word "transparent", as that would be better compatible.