# Can I change the background of select box options to that of a image pattern?

Tags: css

If using a png pattern, I can easily change the background of the select box:

```
select {
     background: url(path/to/some/image.png);
}
```

The same thing will not work for the options of that select box. I can give them a `background-color: red;` for example, but I want to use a pattern (the same one as the select, really).

```
option {
     background: url(path/to/some/image.png); /* will not work */
     background-color: red; /* will work */ 
}
```

My impression is that this isn't possible, but I can't find any proof of that, and I'm hoping it is (somehow). Suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Css background-image issue for <select> & <option>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385490/css-background-image-issue-for-select-option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easy (or I've to say impossible) to change the background-image of an option element properly since every browser renders it differently.
What you could do is to use a javascript plugin (like [choosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)) to simulate a select element.

If you'd like to go with a pure CSS solution I guess it's the best to provide a fallback for browsers that don't accept background images on option elements:

```
background: #red url(path/to/some/image.png) repeat-x 0 0;
```

Comment: It's essentially the same answer as the one in the link @PavelŠtěrba provided. But it is the solution. Thank you