# how to create select option with image in vue js

Tags: vue.js

i want to create a select option with image flag for country code phone number using vue js, i use this script but not working :

I have tried to use v-select and  but nothing worked

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="phone">{{ $t('general.phone_number_otp') }}</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <select v-model="form.phone_number_country_code">
        <option style="background-image:url(https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjc6pK0uIviAhVq4nMBHeenCQwQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.homedepot.com%2Fp%2FSeasonal-Designs-3-ft-x-5-ft-U-S-Flag-RF3N%2F100016521&psig=AOvVaw3itJv4jwOhHprlNfFiEbea&ust=1557387960130973);">+62</option>
        <option>+63</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the result still doesn't display the image that i want

Comment: The URL does not point to an image

Comment: Also, see previous answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385490/css-background-image-issue-for-select-option) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697386/how-to-add-small-thumbnails-to-option-elements-in-a-select-list)